# ListView cannot be found while running code. Says ListActivity must have a ListView attribute with id android.R.id.list

Tags: android, listview, listactivity

I have the listview defined and linked correctly with the id of the listview in the layout xml file. Still I am getting the said error.

I researched over the similar questions posted here but to no avail.

Please help.

```
public class ImageList extends ListActivity {

final static String imageUrls[] = { //some urls

        };

private List<Photo> model = new ArrayList<Photo>();
PhotoAdapter adapter = null;
ListView list = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.imagelist);

    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvImageList);
    // ArrayList<Bitmap> images = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();

    adapter = new PhotoAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            model);

    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    ProduceImageList(imageUrls);

}

public void ProduceImageList(String[] imageUrls) {
    int size = imageUrls.length;
    ImageView imagePlace = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        imagePlace = (ImageView) getListView().getChildAt(i);
        downloadImage task = new downloadImage(imagePlace);
        task.execute(imageUrls[i]);
    }
}
 //asynchronous downloading of images
public class downloadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    // private String url;
    Photo p = new Photo();
    private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;

    public downloadImage(ImageView imageView) {
        imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String localUrl = params[0];
        //here a bitmap download method is used which works fine separately
                    return BitmapDownload.DownloadBitmap(localUrl);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (isCancelled())
            result = null;
        if (imageViewReference != null) {
            ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
            if (imageView != null) {
                p.setPhotoPic(result);
                adapter.add(p);
            }
        }

        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}
  //class defined with getter and setter method
public class Photo {
    private Bitmap pic = null;

    public Bitmap getPhotoPic() {
        return pic;
    }

    public void setPhotoPic(Bitmap incomingPic) {
        this.pic = incomingPic;
    }
}

 //custom ArrayAdapter to hold images
class PhotoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Photo> {

    public PhotoAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            List<Photo> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View row = convertView;
        PhotoHolder holder = null;
        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.imagelistrow, parent,false);
            holder = new PhotoHolder(row);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (PhotoHolder) row.getTag();
        holder.populateFrom(model.get(position));
        return (row);
    }

}

 //holder for the row view
static class PhotoHolder {
    private ImageView imagePlace = null;
    private View row = null;

    PhotoHolder(View row) {
        this.row = row;

        imagePlace = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.ivImageList);
    }

    void populateFrom(Photo p) {

        imagePlace.setImageBitmap(p.getPhotoPic());
    }
}
```

}

My view is...

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical"> 
         <ListView android:id="@+id/lvImageList" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post the XML for `R.id.lvImageList`

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use a custom ListView ID and `ListActivity` at the same time as `ListActivity`, per the error, requires a particular ID for your `ListView`. Currently, you are using a custom ID of `lvImageList`. Either change your Activity to use `Activity` and not `ListActivity` or update your ListView's XML to use:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/android:list"
    ... />
```

Comment: Changing the ListView's ID to `android:id="@+id/android:list"` works also

Answer (score 0):

There are no need to define the custom Listview id in xml file. You just use the android Listview id and there are no need to find view by id in the [ListActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) , you just call the [getListView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#getListView%28%29) to get the listview which is defind in Layout file with default android id